# Are WinRT background task CPU constraints per process or per background task?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm working on adding background functionality to a WinRT application.  Every 15-30 minutes I need to do the following:

1. Send out an HTTP get request to a url
2. Deserialize the results
3. Load local cache and see if any of the items deserialized are new
4. For each new item, do another http request to download the details, deserialize, then save them to cache on disk
5. For each new item do an http get request in order to get the download url for associated files, then start a background download process for each download
6. Save the download operation ids to a cache so the app can pick them up when opened

After reviewing the [MSDN documentation for background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx), it says that at the lock screen your background task only has 2 seconds of CPU time every 15 minutes.

Due to how many things I have to do, does anyone know if this is per application or per background task?